I tried using AI move to move my enemies, but they didn't move
I initially used BP (parent class Character) to control the enemy to move towards the player, but it stays in place without moving.
https://imgur.com/a/ai-bp-parent-class-character-avGLpt0
https://imgur.com/a/stuck-gif-KOql4UC
It has the correct behavior and prints the designated text "GO," but it does not move.
However, another BP (parent class Pawn) can move towards the player correctly. I've considered axis or world static issues, but various searches and adjustments have not worked. Are there any other areas I might be overlooking? Thank you.
I hope to get answers and direction for solving the issue.

AI MoveTo requires a navmesh. For a 2D game such as yours, I would avoid using AI MoveTo and instead move the Actor directly.
With that said, if you want to continue using AI MoveTo here are a couple of reasons why your MoveTo may not work:

missing Navmesh
AI is spawned in at runtime (you'll want to set Auto Possess AI to Placed in World or Spawned)



Based on your feedback, I checked and realized that it’s likely because there are too many actors on the Navmesh, and another friend who is assisting with development used a perspective camera on the player, causing the AI to not move correctly. I am still trying to find a solution. Thank you very much for your reply!!
